# Copy selected text from the CrystalDecisions Report Viewer in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am writing a Crystal Report viewer in C# Visual Studio. One thing that I have noticed is users want to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to copy the text they selected (not using the copy button on the viewer). They said it was a feature in a third party application that we switched over from.

How would I achieve this?

I have set the form `KeyPreview` to true. Using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> still does not copy the selected text.

Looping through all of the CrystalReportViewer objects `Controls`, I have been able to find the control that was highlighted using the `Control.Focused` getter but there is no indication on which section of that `Control` contains the highlighted text. That means I cannot even manually copy the text to the clipboard.

I have also tried using the SendMessage PInvoke with WM_COPY, no success.

Here is the code I am using to step through the viewer looking for the correct data and the PInvoke message I am sending.

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public const int WM_COPY = 0x0301;
CrystalReportViewer viewer;

public void CopySelection()
{
    Control.ControlCollection c = viewer.Controls;

    GetControl(viewer.Controls);

    IntPtr p = SendMessage((int)viewer.Handle, WM_COPY, (int)IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    Console.WriteLine("Copied! " + p);
}

private void GetControl(Control.ControlCollection cItem)
{
    foreach (Control c in cItem)
    {
        if (c.Focused)
            Console.WriteLine(c.Focused);

        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
            GetControl(c.Controls);

        string txt = c.Text;
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Edit:

It seems that after using the 'Find Text' button from the viewer, you are able to copy any text throughout the report with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. Kind of strange. On another note, is there a way to programmatically run the 'Find Text' option?